# Worklight 6.2 Developer Server - Self Signed SSL

Tags: ssl, ibm-mobilefirst, self-signed

We have a HTTPS RESTFul service running in IIS. We are able to successfully call it using the browser. However, when we call the service from a worklight adapter, we are getting the following exception:

"javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException"

The worklight adapter was working perfectly fine when we were using HTTP instead of HTTPS.

We have followed all the steps mentioned in the documentation:

1. Create certificate using keytool in the IIS server. Bind it to the RestFul service.
2. Exporting the public key to a .cert file
3. Importing the file into Worklight keystore
4. Mentioned https as the protocol in the adapter.xml.

We have even verified the default.keystore of the worklight, it is matching with the certificate present in the IIS server.

We don't need mutual authentication. We just want to use SSL in the RestFul service deployed in the IIS.

Thanks,
Pavan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the certificate to your device's trust store. Since it is self signed, devices will not trust them by default. To do so, follow the steps here for your device's OS: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_ssl_config.html?lang=en

Specifically, look at [this for iOS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_installing_root_CA_iOS.html) and [this one for Android.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_installing_root_CA_android.html)

Comment: The issue is not SSL between the device and worklight. The issue is the SSL between the worklight server and the API server.

Following is our architecture:
Device -> Worklight -> API

Also, we are using self-signed certificates for the API server.

Comment: Oh ok. In that case, make sure to add the Certificate Authority that you used to create your certificate, or if you didn't use a CA to create your certificate, then add your certificate into your API server's trust store. It is the same concept as with the device, but rather on the server. This will vary depending on what your API server is, so I suggest searching, for example "add certificate to tomcat server".

Comment: We are using Windows and we have added the certificate to trusted store in both worklight server and the API server, but still getting the same exception.